# Paste an image from clipboard to a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to paste an image from clipboard to an excel cell using vba.
i could find a code like this :

```
If My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsImage() Then
Dim grabpicture = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetImage()
PictureBox1.Image = grabpicture
End If
```

but here grabpicture variable is an object. how to update a cell from an image object.
like this,

```
Sheet1.Range("D11").Value = grabpicture
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pictures are not inserted into cells. Pictures are inserted onto the sheet and then may be aligned so that the top left corner visually matches top left corner of some cell.

To insert a picture from the clipboard, you use `Sheet1.Paste()`.

Answer (score 5):

To move image from one sheet to another through clipboard standard methods Copy-Paste are used. For Paste method you must define the range where the image is to be pasted, for example (you may skip Destination parameter):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C5").Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D5")
```

A picture is inserted in the specified region, but some peculiarities exist:

- for Office 2003 pasted image is not binded exactly to upper-left
  corner of the range; if you define an alone cell the image may get
  the position more left and lower, even may get the adjacent cell; so
  you must execute realign procedure using Top and Left  properties
  (see below);
- for Office 2003 pasted picture IS NOR selected, so special procedure
  must be done to identify the image in Shapes collection;
- for Office 2007 image is selected and binded to upper-left corner of
  the specified range, so Selection property can be used to change the
  image property in the collection (Name for example);
- pasted image index in Shapes collection becomes the upmost BUT AMONG
  THE PICTURES set (Type=msoPicture); in Office 2003 Shapes are
  groupped so that first is the block of controls (Lstbox, Combobox,
  etc.) and images block is latter, so pasted image index is in fact
  the last in all collection; for Office 2007 images block turns out to
  be BEFORE the block of controls, therefore you should search the
  index of the last pasted image between the elements of IMAGE BLOCK
  (see example below);
- to deselect pasted image (not to delete it by accident) you should
  move focus to any cell/ for example as Range("A1").Select.

Hence, to write a universal program that works correctly either in Office 2003, or Office 2007 environment you should:

- first, use special procedure to find out the pasted image (the reference, or index, of it in Shapes collection);
- second, make image alignment to upper-left corner of the range where the image is pasted;
- third, move focus to another cell.

Below is the Function that defines the index of last pasted image in the Shapes collection:

```
Function GetIndexPastedPicture() As Integer
' Pasted picture has the upmost index among the PICTURE block 
' But it is not necessarily the last inde[ in whole collection
' set reference to target sheet with pasted image
Set ThisDBSheet = Workbooks("BookName.xls").Worksheets("SheetName")
Dim sh As Shape, picIdx As Integer
picIdx = 0 ' initial value of index in Shapes collection, starts from 1
For Each sh In ThisDBSheet.Shapes
    If sh.Type = msoPicture Then ' image found
        picIdx = sh.ZOrderPosition ' image index
    End If
Next
' after For loop, picIdx - is the last index in PICTURE block 
GetIndexPastedPicture = picIdx
End Function
```

Then (assuming that Clipboard already has the proper image) the procedure  to paste image looks like following:

```
Sub InsPicFromClipbrd(sInsCell As String, sPicName As String)
' Image is pasted to cell with name sInsCell,
' it is aligned to upper-left corner of the cell, 
' pasted image gets name sPicName in Shapes collection
' set reference to target sheet with pasted image
Set ThisDBSheet = Workbooks("BookName.xls").Worksheets("SheetName")
ThisDBSheet.Paste Destination:=Range(sInsCell) ' paste image fom clipboard
c1 = GetIndexPastedPicture() ' get index of pasted image (see above)
With ThisDBSheet.Shapes.Item(c1) ' correct the properties of the pasted image 
    .Top = Range(sInsCell).Top ' top alignment
    .Left = Range(sInsCell).Left ' left alignment
    .Name = sPicName ' assign new name
End With
Range("I18").Activate ' move focus from image
End Sub 'InsPicFromClipbrd
```

Answer (score 1):

Good evening...
This bit of code will copy whatever image is in your windows PC clipboard and paste it to a worksheet tab "Sheet1" and then copy it to a new chart.  The chart will then be exported as a jpg file to a network folder with name given in the code.

Sub Count_Shapes_click()
    ' NOTE: Count_Shapes is a command button

```
' NOTE: MyChart is the new chart where the image will eventually be copied to
'       in order to then be exported as a jpg file
Dim MyChart As Chart


' NOTE: The workbook sheet "Sheet1" will be made the active sheet
Sheet1.Activate

' NOTE: This will past whatever is currently in the clipboard to the active sheet
'       So, make sure that your image is what was most recently copied
'
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:zz10")

' NOTE: This is creating the new Chart
    Set MyChart = Charts.Add

' NOTE: This is name the new chart
MyChart.Name = "HELLO"

' NOTE: This is moving the chart to the sheet where the picture is
Set MyChart = MyChart.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1")

' NOTE: This is making the width and height of the MyChart equal to whatever image you copied to the clipboard
MyChart.ChartArea.Width = Sheet1.Shapes(2).Width
MyChart.ChartArea.Height = Sheet1.Shapes(2).Height

' NOTE: This is removing the shape container boarder
MyChart.Parent.Border.LineStyle = 0

' NOTE: This is copying the image that was pasted to the sheet "Sheet1"
Sheet1.Shapes(2).Copy

' NOTE: This is selecting or making active the ChartArea of MyChart
MyChart.ChartArea.Select

' NOTE: This is pasting the image that was just copied via VBA of EXCEL into the MyChart ChartArea
MyChart.Paste

' NOTE: This is exporting the MyChart to a jpg file.
'       Filename:="location of folder\name of the file.XXX"
'       FilterName:="jpg" read about this at - > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Chart.Export
MyChart.Export Filename:="J:\TEMP\LIBERTY\Images\HI Me.jpg", FilterName:="jpg"

' NOTE: Make cell (Row 1, Column A) the active cell
Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Activate

' NOTE: Delete the Chart you created earlier
Sheet1.ChartObjects(Sheet1.ChartObjects.Count).Delete

' NOTE: Delete the (hopefully) only 1 shape (image pasted ealier) on the sheet "Sheet1"
Sheet1.Shapes(1).Delete
```

End Sub

Comment: Using the chart object to save the shape is a good idea. To make the chart  fill transparent, you can add 'MyChart.ChartArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse.'