# Pasting an image from clipboard using VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that allows the user to paste an image (like a screenshot) onto my spreadsheet.

I came across this solution but I do not understand it ([Paste an image from clipboard to a cell in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684920/paste-an-image-from-clipboard-to-a-cell-in-excel))

What I need to achieve:
1) User takes a screenshot, like with Snipping Tool
2) Allow user to paste that image in the clipboard onto a specified area (and size) on Sheet 1, aligned to cell J55.
3) Also later, the user should be able to re-use that image (another macro button that pastes that image onto another sheet)

I tried a few codes, like:

```js
If My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsImage() Then
Dim grabpicture = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetImage()
PictureBox1.Image = grabpicture
End If
```

but I get an error at "Dim grabpicture".

We are using Office 2010.

Comment: Dim is used to dimension variable *types*. Try `Set grabpicture = `.. though I suspect there's more problems then just that.

Comment: You're right. Set grabicture = does help, but it doesn't solve my problem. The solution below seems to work, but it hasn't achieved everything I need at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

The code snippet you were trying is not VBA. Here's how you would paste from the clipboard in Excel-VBA:

```
 Sheet1.Paste Destination:= Sheet1.Range("J55"), Link:= False
```

This will paste whatever was in the clipboard onto Sheet1, aligned to cell J55. If the clipboard had an image, that image will be pasted.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Now I need to do 2 more things:  
1) How do I ensure that the clipboard contains an image before pasting? I tried using GetFromClipboard but it doesn't seem to work.  
2) In order for me to re-use this image again later, I would need to assign an "ID" to it. What is the best way to do it? The image needs to be used in another sheet.

Comment: @Baineteo - The first question in your comment is an entirely separate question and should be posed as such on SO. As the answer to your original question was answered here. For the 2nd question, perhaps save the image to a location on your network and store that path name for use later to insert a picture.

Comment: Hi Scott, point noted. I'll go on and re-post the question to better reflect condition.